# Asterisk PBX Manager not saving changes

Tags: asterisk, pbx

We are implementing Asterisk 11.4 and using the native PostgreSQL database to store call data. So far, we have not been able to change the admin password through the PBX manager.

The password gets changed in the manager.conf file. However, the PBX Manager does not change the password in the PostgreSQL database, from which it reads the password for logging in.

For security, I accessed the database and changed the default password via an sql command. The manager was then reloaded through the Asterisk CLI so that the new password is used.

Additionally, when a new user is created through the PBX manager the changes are not saved. The data is still present if the Users page is navigated away from. However, if you log out of then back into the manager, the new user is gone.

All advice and critiques are appreciated.

Comment: (Late) Update - The Native Asterisk PBX manager does not have the ability to interface with the PostgreSQL database.  A proprietary UI had to be developed to connect the two.